# Running bash script from PHP halts

Tags: php, bash

**EDIT**

It seems that I cannot `cat /dev/urandom` from a PHP script, please keep this in mind while reading the following

**/EDIT**

I ran into an issue while trying to execute a BASH script from PHP, seems to be halting at generating a rand directory (variable `generate`) I can see if I change the variable string to something like `foo` as I did in the commented out portion of the script this executes appropriately.

What is the issue with sghell_exec'ing `cat /dev/urandom | tr -dc 'a-zA-Z0-9' | fold -w 32 | head -n 1` is this a (possibly) restricted command sequence to user(s) www-data (DEB based system) or httpd (RHEL based system)

The bash script

```
#!/bin/bash

# INP : co.sh ${website} ${branch} ${hash}

set -x # trace

declare -r hostname='localhost'

# bricks
declare -r generate=$(cat /dev/urandom | tr -dc 'a-zA-Z0-9' | fold -w 32 | head -n 1)

# works
#declare -r generate='foo'

declare -r archive="$1" # git repository name
declare -r branchd="$2" # git repo branch name
declare -r hashmap="$3" # git blob hash (6/~)


# if repository or branch is empty...
if [ '' == "${archive}" ] || [ '' == "${branchd}" ]; then

   [ '' == "${archive}" ] &&  echo -e "ERR: Archive must be defined."
   [ '' == "${branchd}" ] &&  echo -e "ERR: Branch must be defined."

       exit 1 # err fatal
fi

    # clone repository to rand directory
    git clone "git@${hostname}:web-archive/${archive}.git" "/var/www/html/${generate}"
    cd "/var/www/html/${generate}" && git checkout "${branchd}"

    position='HEAD' # pre-warm

    [ '' != "${hashmap}" ] &&
    {
        git reset "${hashmap}" --hard   # move to hash blob
        position="${hashmap}"           # override position
    }

    # encode for push
    json="{'s':'${archive}','b':'${branchd}','h':'${position}','d':'${generate}'}"

echo -e "\nSUCC: ${json}"
```

The test runner script

```
#!/usr/bin/php
<?php

$dir=__DIR__; // curr

$site_name='www.foo.com';

$rev_hash='feb2da';

$cmd="$dir/co.sh " . escapeshellarg($site_name) . " 'render' " . escapeshellarg($rev_hash);

echo "running $cmd\n";
$ret = passthru($cmd,$return_status));
```

trace log

```
running /{dir_path}/co.sh 'www.foo.com' 'render' 'feb2da'
+ declare -r hostname=localhost
++ cat /dev/urandom
++ fold -w 32
++ head -n 1
++ tr -dc a-zA-Z0-9
```

Comment: Are you running the script in the context of a PHP session? In such case, check part 2 of the answer to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13690490/executing-a-program-from-php-hangs-apache

Comment: @Claudix - that seems pretty Windows-specific. ehime - is the actual bash script failing when you try to run it, or only when run via that test runner? What error(s), if any, do you get?

Comment: Can you check the permissions of /dev/urandom?

Comment: @admdrew AFAIK the same issue happens on UNIX platforms.

Comment: @Claudix - Could be, although I couldn't find anything that referenced `*nix` in there, including the [linked bug](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=44942).

Comment: @admdrew Mm.. I see. Maybe I've read about this somewhere else. You might be right! :D

Comment: @admdrew it is failing via the test runner, this work fin in a terminal by itself

Comment: @LajosVeres perms are assigned to `root` ;) `crw-rw-rw-   1 root root      1,   9 Nov 25 10:20 urandom`

Comment: @LajosVeres it seems like cat'ing /dev/urandom is not working from when executed through PHP, would this mean that the script is most likely taking on perms of the parent, and the parent does not have read on /dev? This is very strange since `php -i |grep rand` produces `session.entropy_file => /dev/urandom => /dev/urandom` which belies the fact we use /dev/urandom already?

Comment: @ehime - Do you *need* to actually use `/dev/urandom`? Why can't you use `$RANDOM`?

Comment: @admdrew good point, i believe I did it since I'm getting very small random sequences instead of 32~ chars that have low probability of colliding

Comment: Honestly keeping the above in mind, I can use `openssl rand -base64 36 | tr -dc 'a-zA-Z0-9'` just as well without worrying about accessing /dev/urandom

Comment: @ehime - Yeah, even better than `$RANDOM` for sure.

Comment: @admdrew if you want to post that as a Answer I'll give you some free points for helping me think through it ;)

Comment: Haha. Actually, you should answer your own question; totally acceptable to do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Due to PHP not liking to operate on `/dev/urandom` the following is an acceptable compromise

`openssl rand -base64 36 | tr -dc 'a-zA-Z0-9'`

Comment: lmao, completely worth the extra bandwidth ;)