# WAMP: Apache processes are stuck

Tags: php, apache, wampserver

I am running WAMP 2.2, Apache 2.2.9 and PHP 5.4 on Windows 7 64 bit. I recently got a strange issue. After some time I am unable to view any static resource. The browser just loads forever. I tried to view individual images but all I see is loading bar. When I reboot windows this problem goes away for few minutes. Here is what I tried:

1. Changed Apache server name from `localhost:8088` to `127.0.0.1:8088`
2. Changed apache port
3. Added `127.0.0.1 localhost` entry in `c:\windows\system32\drivers\etc\hosts`
4. Stopped all services/applications that I felt may cause the problem

I sniffed http packets and found all requests are in pending. I monitored httpd process and noticed many processes are in waiting chain. Please see following images:

[image: http requests]

[image: httpd resource monitor]

How do I find out what's causing the apache processes to load forever?

Comment: Is your Apache server attending other requests that yield an external program execution from PHP? In such case I faced a similar issue which I documented here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13690490/executing-a-program-from-php-hangs-apache (see point 2 of the answer)

Comment: @Claudix no this is not the case. It's just static files i.e. `http://localhost:8088/image.png, layout.css, etc`.

Answer (score 1):

Could you try writing the following lines in httpd.conf and restarting Apache?

```
AcceptFilter http none
AcceptFilter https none
```

These directives have something to do with Windows' socket API and HTTP protocol buffering. See http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html